# Android: Send URI from one activity to another and then display it in ImageView

Tags: string, arraylist, android-activity, imageview, uri

I am working on an app with OpenCV and currently if the camera recognises certain text areas on a document, it converts them into strings and it also extracts a cropped image from the camera frame for every text area and stores it into a temporary directory.

I know the file paths of those images and I tried extracting them into separate URI strings in my camera_activity and then pass them with Intent to another activity where they should be reconverted from string to URI and then displayed as images into an ImageView. Here is my code so far:

**camera_activity** using OpenCV JavaCamera View:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    OcrResponse resp = ocr.ExtractUserIdData(mRgba, false);
    if (resp.ok) {

        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> uriStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Uri> uriArray = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri;
        String uriStr;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity_output.class);

        for (Response_data data : resp.data) {

            System.out.println(data.header + ": " + data.details.trim());
            strings.add(data.header + ": " + data.details);

            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("dir/" + data.header.replace(' ', '_') + ".png"));
            uriStr = uri.toString();
            uriStrings.add(uriStr);

            }
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("string1", strings);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("uri_img", uriStrings);

        startActivity(intent);

        [...]
   }
}
```

Explaining this code a little. The OCR recognises certain text areas from the document and extracts them as strings (with the format "Headers: Description"). The **for** statement does just that, add them into a string array called *strings* and that array is sent into a new activity called **output_activity** via Intent and .putStringArrayListExtra. So far so good.

This is the code for **output_activity**:

```
public class activity_output extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
ImageView iv;

ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arraylistUri = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Uri> uri = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_output);

    text = findViewById(R.id.output_text1);
    iv = findViewById(R.id.img_out);

    arraylist = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("string1");
    arraylistUri = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("uri_img");
    //uri = (ArrayList<Uri>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("img");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder builderU = new StringBuilder();
    //StringBuilder uriBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String s : arraylist) {
        builder.append(s).append("\n\n");
    }

    for (String d : arraylistUri) {
       builderU.append(d);
    }

    text.setText(builder.toString());
    //iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriBuilder.toString()));
```

Here I receive the string array and convert it into a TextView. Everything works neat, all the correct data is written in that activity. No doubt my code works so far. Here is a screenshot: [A little more work on the layout, but functionally it's good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd6AO.jpg)

Now, going back to the **camera_activity**, you can see that inside the for statement I am trying to get an URI from the image path from each cropped piece (inside the 'uri' variable) and then convert it into a string called 'uriStr'. Then I add each string to another arraylist called 'UriStrings' and send it to **output_activity**.

Finally comes my question: How exactly do I use the string containing the URI inside **output_activity** so I can display those cropped images in an ImageView? The method I used doesn't work (unsurprisingly) and I need a quick solution.

Thank you and *May your roads lead you to warm sands*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way around the URI. Here is the solution I found if somebody will ever be interested:

I didn't send anything from my **camera_activity** anymore, only used the **output_activity**.

```
File mFile = new 
 File("/data/user/0/com.blissk.myapplication/cacheExtractedSerialNumber.png");

Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

Bitmap MBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap,(int)(mBitmap.getWidth()*4),(int)(mBitmap.getHeight()*4),true);

ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.img_out);

iv.setImageBitmap(MBitmap);
```

I am currently a dummy in Java and since the app is supposed destroy all scanned documentation after you exit the cameraview (for privacy reasons), I thought the paths for the cached images would not work after switching to the **output_activity** and thought they needed to be sent there through an Intent. They did work and the program successfully destroyed all data after the **output_activity** was finished().

Basically my code above will work for any app that uses cached images, converts them as bitmaps, resizes them (in my case I needed to enlarge them 4 times) and displays them